# CSS child selector applying to nested elements

Tags: css

I want to make the paragraph that is a direct child of the div foo have blue text and all other paragraphs have blue text, but the css I have written is apply that style to nested

tags inside the div too.

CSS:

```
p {
  color:red;
}

#foo > p{
 color: blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <link type="test/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="foo">
  <p>
      This is the first line.<br/>
      This is the second line
      <p>Nested Paragraph</p>
  </p>
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph in new div</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output (Chrome)

This is the first line. (blue)
This is the second line (blue)

Nested Paragraph (blue)

Paragraph in new div (red)

Comment: I'm afraid you have to edit your question to make it clearer... much clearer to make a bit of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `p` element don't have another `p` element inside it. The browser behavior is put the nested `p` outside. Because of that all of your paragraphs are childrens of `#foo` element.

The following HTML:

```
<p>
    This is the first line.
    This is the second line
    <p>Nested Paragraph</p>
</p>
```

Causes this output:

```
<p>
    This is the first line.
    This is the second line
</p>
<p>Nested Paragraph</p>
```

Check the outputted HTML in the following fiddle and you can see what I'm saying: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ahse0jzg/

Answer (score 1):

[`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) elements may only contain [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content).

[`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) elements are considered [flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), and as such your markup is invalid and parsed poorly. You can not nest [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) elements.

Your CSS selectors would work with proper HTML.